# What is the right algorithm to detect segmentations of a line chart?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, machine-learning, decomposition

To be concrete, given 2D numerical data as is shown as line plots below. There are peaks on a background average movement (with small vibrations). We want to find the values of pairs (x1, x2) if those peaks drops down to average; or (x1) only if the line doesn't back to the average.
[image: how to find x1 and x2 from data without plotting?]
[image: how to find x1 from data without plotting?]

There are thousands of such 2D data.

What is the right statistic or machine learning algorithm to find x1 and x2 above without plotting?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it looks like you need to know some threshold to detect peaks:

1. detect bottom edge (Xbe)
2. calculate the moving average (until the last edge)
3. detect peak itself (current value - average value > threshold)
4. start of peak found: X1=Xbe
5. detect peak end (current value - average value < threshold)
6. detect bottom age (Xbe)
7. end of peak found: X2=Xbe

Bottom edge detection in the simplest way is when you make moving subtract for two consecutive values and sign changes from negative to positive.

Comment: maybe thresholds can be derived from overall mins and maxs of the data.